# wp_nav_menu put PHP code in Navigation Label

Tags: php, wordpress

First time here, wonder if you can use PHP directly in the field Label Navigation Menu WP. At the moment the situation is as follows ... I show you two images to understand better what I'm trying to do:

http://d.pr/i/nZ63

and this is the output of the page:

http://d.pr/i/g2sN

I want to do this is quite unusual, but also using the same php code in the description I get the same problem as above. If you use the HTML code example:`<p><span>` there is no problem.

Tnx U all.

---

ok. This is the current Test situation:

```
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'top_navigation',
    'menu_class' => 'nav',
        //'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
            'container' => false,
            //'echo' => false,
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '<span>' . wp_title() . '</span>,
```

no errors, no output red, but no title test! 
I forget something?

Comment: I don't know the plugin/feature you are using, but I can say that it's highly unlikely this will work.  Due to how PHP evaluates and how web servers work, you'd have to actually "eval" the incoming values from that form in the template... the potential damage that could be done to the system from something like that would be enormous.  

You could simply inject PHP code that would delete all files in the filesystem, and on a shared server with poorly managed permissions, that could do a lot of damage, and cost someone a lot of money.

Comment: What are you trying to do, more explicitly, not with images - but in terms of the business requirement?

Comment: I've re-tagged your question assuming that WP stands for "WordPress". Please correct it yourself if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do not usually use plugins and even in this case, I would call a function that lists out subscribers/authors.

Recalling in this way: `<?php attrac_list_authors(); ?>` in any part of my WordPress, it works. If I call the function in the Navigation Label menu or in the description, this returns in an unusual output.

At the time of this writing, I tried to use:

```
'after' => '<span>' . attrac_list_authors(); . '</span>,
```

and seems to give better results, but I think it is the best solution.